# Single Sign-on - PingfFederate - How to set the date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, pingfederate

I noticed when PingFederate(PF) sends the date it is off by a day from my Rails app.  It appears that the PF date is the one off by a day.  For example in the PF SAML response I get:

```
<saml:Assertion ID="pEaf1kce93SpAxfIpuohOv6QP-T" IssueInstant="2014-05-03T03:15:20.020Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
```

and

```
 <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-05-03T03:10:20.021Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-05-03T03:20:20.021Z">
```

whereas in Rails I get

```
 Time.now = 2014-05-02 20:15:19 -0700
```

which makes me think that I need to set the date in PF.  Note that PF is running on the same computer that the Rails app is running on.

Is there a way to set the date in PF?

The time is off as well.  Is there a way in PF to set the time too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAML assertions are always in UTC. Which is what PingFed is using. Set your Rails application to use UTC as well.

I don't see why you think that the time is off. Your time from Rails is 2015 and -7.  That means in UTC, it's tomorrow at 0315 - when it was issued. PingFed is setting an allowance of +/-5 minutes, so the SP should not accept it before 0310 or after 0320.

Your server and PingFed are correct so far...

Comment: Is it possible to set the allowance to more than +/- 5 minutes?

Comment: I found I think where to do this.  It's inSP Connection -> Browser SSO -> Assertion Lifetime.